# How to install vCenter7 ca-certificate to Ubuntu18.04

Tags: 18.04, ssl

I'm having trouble with installing ca-certificate of vmware vCenter server to Ubuntu18.04.

I've downloaded ca-certificates from vCenter server and unzipped it. There're 4 files as shown in the below for linux are included. The ones with extension .0 is the ca-certificate and with .r0 is CRL file.

```
/usr/share/ca-certificates/local/
├── 8a586298.0
├── 8a586298.r0
├── c7214310.0
└── c7214310.r0
```

I added paths of all 4 files to /etc/ca-certificates.conf and ran update-ca-certificates but got the following message said it was not added to ca-certificates.crt. What am I missing?

```
$ sudo update-ca-certificates
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
rehash: warning: skipping ca-certificates.crt,it does not contain exactly one certificate or CRL
2 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
done.
```